# How to wait until an element no longer exists in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am testing a UI in which the user clicks a delete button and a table entry disappears. As such, I want to be able to check that the table entry no longer exists.

I have tried using `ExpectedConditions.not()` to invert `ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated()`, hoping that it would mean "expect that there is not a presence of the specified element". My code is like so:

```
browser.navigate().to("http://stackoverflow.com");
new WebDriverWait(browser, 1).until(
        ExpectedConditions.not(
                ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("foo"))));
```

However, I found that even doing this, I get a `TimeoutExpcetion` caused by a `NoSuchElementException` saying that the element "foo" does not exist. Of course, having no such element is what I want, but I don't want an exception to be thrown.

So how can I wait until an element no longer exists? I would prefer an example that does not rely on catching an exception if at all possible (as I understand it, exceptions should be thrown for exceptional behavior).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can also use -

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
```

If you go through [the source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d1a06e59f242e7920c3b7ba8f6dcd2f546857b4b/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#L572) of it you can see that both `NoSuchElementException` and `staleElementReferenceException` are handled.

```
/**
   * An expectation for checking that an element is either invisible or not
   * present on the DOM.
   *
   * @param locator used to find the element
   */
  public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> invisibilityOfElementLocated(
      final By locator) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
          return !(findElement(locator, driver).isDisplayed());
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
          // Returns true because the element is not present in DOM. The
          // try block checks if the element is present but is invisible.
          return true;
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
          // Returns true because stale element reference implies that element
          // is no longer visible.
          return true;
        }
      }
```

Comment: odd syntax error in above code: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements

Answer (score 5):

The solution would still rely on exception-handling. And this is pretty much ok, even [standard Expected Conditions](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#453) rely on exceptions being thrown by `findElement()`.

The idea is to create a *custom Expected Condition*:

```
  public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> absenceOfElementLocated(
      final By locator) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
          driver.findElement(locator);
          return false;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
          return true;
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
          return true;
        }
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return "element to not being present: " + locator;
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: Your answer works great, but I decided to accept another answer since there seems to be a built in version that does exactly what I want. Still, your answer is a great guideline!

Comment: @Thunderforge thanks, I was aware about the method. Though I was assuming you need to wait for an element not be present in DOM as opposed to becoming invisible. Anyway, glad it is solved!

Comment: I discovered that the method also handles it being absent from the DOM, not just if it is invisible. Since the former is my use case and I don't care about the latter, it works for me and saves the effort of rolling my own.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you simply find the size of `elements`. We know the the collection of elements' *size* would be **0** if *element* does not exist.

```
if(driver.findElements(By.id("foo").size() > 0 ){
    //It should fail
}else{
    //pass
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't wait for the element to no longer exist; it just checks it once.

Comment: The solution by @VivekSingh is the best imo to not reinvent the wheel, but this solution would be great combined with an Expected Condition if the situation was slightly different. Would look something like this: `(new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).withMessage("element was still displayed after timeout").until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) d -> d.findElements(By.id("foo").size() > 0));`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why but `ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(element)` is the only work for me while `ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By)`, `!ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By)` ... not. Try it!

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

```
// pseudo code
public Fun<driver,webelement> ElemtDisappear(locator)
{
    webelement element=null;
    iList<webelement> elemt =null;
    return driver=>
    {
    try
    {
    elemt = driver.findelements(By.locator);
    if(elemt.count!=0)
    {
    element=driver.findelement(By.locator);
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
    return(elemnt==0)?element:null;
};

// call function
public void waitforelemDiappear(driver,locator)
{
    webdriverwaiter wait = new webdriverwaiter(driver,time);
    try
    {
    wait.until(ElemtDisappear(locator));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

As findelement throws exception on element unaviability.so i implemented using findelements. please feel free to correct and use it as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to fix this for me in efficient way, used following C# code to handle this, you may convert it to Java

```
    public bool WaitForElementDisapper(By element)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (driver.FindElement(element).Displayed)
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
                catch (NoSuchElementException)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error(e.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Good news, it's built in now (I'm using Node.js in 2021)

It looks like `elementIsNotVisible` has been added to `until` after the previous answers were given. I'm using selenium webdriver `4.0.0-beta.3`

Check it out:

```
const timeout = 60 * 1000; // 60 seconds
const element = await driver.findElement(By.id(elementId));

// this is the important line 
await driver.wait(until.elementIsNotVisible(element), timeout);
```

Comment: the description of this function is: `Creates a condition that will wait for the given element to be in the DOM, yet not visible to the user.` That is not what most people are looking for here. Myself, and likely others are looking for a way to assert an element is NOT in the dom, not that is is in the dom but just invisible

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following logic:

C# code sinppet:

```
//wait is the instance of WebDriverWait
wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("your element expath")).Count == 0);
```

Notice how I use `FindElements` that does NOT throw `NoSuchElementException` which is swallowed by `Until()` function. So when element is gone collection size is zero.