# How to read element on Page when its loading in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to automate a Gmail login Page where I face one issue. 
Replication steps:

1. Update User Name and Password
2. Click on Sign Button.
   There will be "Loading Page" before the main Inbox Page. I need to validate that this Loading page appeared after the sign-in click and before Inbox Page in Gmail.

Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: You can try to get `HTML` for the "loading" `div` to be able to create selector and then assert whether this `div` appears (is visible) after page redirection

Comment: Yes, you should get the selector for the "Loading" message and check for its invisibility. Please check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082862/how-to-wait-until-an-element-no-longer-exists-in-selenium