# Not able to find element of a web application in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click a button using selenium webdriver

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='addLog']")).click();
```

But am getting an error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <button id="addLog" type="button" class="btn btn-awh1" onclick="addLog()">...</button> is not clickable at point (516, 209). Other element would receive the click: <div id="BBOverlay" style="opacity: 0.216303; width: 1034px; height: 506px;"></div>
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Operation Button -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4" />
            <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button id="addLog" class="btn btn-awh1" type="button"     onclick="addLog()">
                    Create My Health Log
                      <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Of Operation Button -->
</div>
```

The code before this operation button is

```
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active" role="presentation">
    <a href="#log" aria-controls="log" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">My Health Log</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#details" aria-controls="details" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">My Health Details</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
    <li role="presentation">
    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content" style="margin-top:25px">
    <!-- My Health Log -->
    <div id="log" class="tab-pane active center" role="tabpanel">
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It clearly says you have an overlay over that button. Do you have any loading animation like blockUI that covers your whole page, maybe waiting for rest response?

Comment: Please post a link to the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the error message, it states that there is an element covering the element you are trying to click. I'm not sure what the element is

```
<div id="BBOverlay" style="opacity: 0.216303; width: 1034px; height: 506px;"></div>
```

but from the id it looks like it's an overlay of some sort. I would wait for that element to be invisible and then click the desired button. I can't know if that will work for sure given the info you've provided so you'll have to try it and let me know.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("BBOverlay")));
driver.findElement(By.id("addLog")).click();
```

Comment: I tried this , still i am not able to click the button, it instead clicks another tab

Comment: Is that element which you want to click is at bottom of page and you need to scroll?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't two elements on the page with the same ID? The ID matches the one you provided so it shouldn't click some random other element. Please update the code in your question with what you are current trying (more than just the one line). A link to the page would solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following `xpath` if it works for you:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Create My Health Log')]")).click();
```

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-awh1']")).click();
```

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='addLog'][@class='btn btn-awh1']")).click();
```

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn-group #addLog")).click();
```

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".row .form-group .col-md-4 .btn-group #addLog")).click();
```

I guess the element is below in page and you need to scroll for it:
This will work I guess

```
WebElement elements = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-awh1']"))   
Thread.sleep(3000L);
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
int yPosition = elements.getLocation().getY();
js.executeScript("window.scroll (0, " + yPosition + ") ");
Thread.sleep(3000L);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-awh1']")).click();
```

Let me know if any of them works for you.

Comment: I tried both , doesn't work for me and still the same error message.

Comment: Thanks for this! Working fine now.

Comment: Do not use thread.sleep in selenium! It will make your tests slower and non-deterministic. If you have an overlay, wait until this overlay is not visible. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29084080/143585

Comment: There are many `waits` you can use them. I just told hard wait just to check whether element is visible or not.

Comment: @KishanPatel Just realised there's some mistake. This code is actually clicking on another tab instead of the button, not sure why.

Comment: Which xpath are you using?

Comment: @KishanPatel i tried both xpath's which you had provided

Comment: And the Third One also? Just see it and also check your Html structure

Comment: Share Html for My Health Details also.

Comment: Yes, i tried the third one as well, its detecting the other tab instead of button

Comment: Please Share html of that other tab

Comment: <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="active" role="presentation">
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#details" aria-controls="details" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">My Health Details</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <li role="presentation">
        </ul>

Comment: Do put some wait before the page is fully loaded.

Comment: @PrasanShetty it's tough to read the HTML DOM from the comments. Can you update the question with the new HTML DOM?

Comment: Did you checked by `cssselector` ? Option 4 and 5th ?

Comment: Yes i tried all the options(including wait)Its still the same. Can't really click the intended button.Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Can you share the website?