# Selenium Java : wait until clickable

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber-java, webdriverwait

I am stuck at a situation with selenium wait. I am using Selenium Java with cucumber.
On click of a button a new page loads but the contents aren't yet made clickable. A grey screen blocker is displayed while the page loads on the back so as to make it non-editable till the full page is loaded. So I couldn't use waitforpageload or wait for element to be visible as they both return true as the elements are available in the background. 
I have tried to use a condition to check if the elements are clickable to make sure that the page loads fully. But that didn't work either. Once the page loads at the back ground, further checks are executed and the test ends up in an error.

I have also tried waituntilelementis visible:

```
public static void waitUntilTextIsInvisible(final String text, final int timeoutInSecs)
    {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(text))
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            (new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, timeoutInSecs))
                    .until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public Boolean apply(final WebDriver d)
                        {
                            return SeleniumUtils.findElementsContainingText(text, d).size() == 0;
                        }
                    });
        }
        catch (TimeoutException e)
        {
            LOG.error("Exception on page " + _webDriver.getCurrentUrl()
                    + " waiting for text " + text + " to be visible");
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

But that even returned a true and went onto execute the next step.
How do I make selenium to wait for the grey screen to be gone and then looks for contents on the page.

Any responses would be appreciated.

-Lakshmi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait until an element no longer exists in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082862/how-to-wait-until-an-element-no-longer-exists-in-selenium)

Comment: You should add a tag for the language you want also.

Answer (score 0):

You can pause the browser when the page loads and the grey screen blocker appears. Get the xpath for it and wait till it's no longer present. Let me know if this helps.