# Explicit wait not working for my code as that line of code is not waiting for that element to be visible or clickable

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Explicit wait is not waiting for the element to be clickable when I enter the username and password

Scenario:

1. Tap on signin on whataburger.com
2. Enter username and password
3. Wait for signin button to be enabled and click on signin (This is the step where selenium is not waiting for the element to be enabled and click )

I have tried all the explicit wait functionality using element to be clickable, presence of element, visibility of element

```
private static WebDriver driver;
private static WebDriverWait wait;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Browsxers a = new Browsxers();
    try {
        driver = a.browse(driver);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.get("https://wbdotcomqa.azurewebsites.net/home");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='navbar']/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/a/span[1]")).click();
 Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("Whataburgerqa86+1112@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("burger01");


WebElement wb = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn wb-btn-default center-block']")));
wb.click();
```

no error selenium acts like its clicked the button when it was disabled

Comment: Below is HTML snippet when the button is disabled

Comment: <button _ngcontent-c14="" class="btn wb-btn-default center-block" type="submit" disabled=""> Sign In <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></button>

Comment: HTML Snippet when enabled:  <button _ngcontent-c14="" class="btn wb-btn-default center-block" type="submit"> Sign In <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></button>

Answer (score 1):

In your page when the credentials inputs are not filled there is a `disabled` [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp) being added to the form.

[image]

and when the credentials are not empty - the `disabled` attribute goes away:

[image]

Assuming above situation personally I would rather go for the following approach:

1. Wait until the button with the `disabled` attribute disappears
2. Wait until the button without the `disabled` attribute becomes clickable

The relevant code lines would be:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn wb-btn-default center-block' and @disabled]")));
WebElement wb = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn wb-btn-default center-block' and not(@disabled)]")));
```

More information:

- [XPath Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)
- [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)
- [How to wait until an element no longer exists in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082862/how-to-wait-until-an-element-no-longer-exists-in-selenium)

Comment: Hi,thanks for looking into this issue but still the above statements were not working and selenium was clicking the sign in button when it was disabled