# Select row from table in Selenium based on certain text/values

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to be able to click on any part of a row that meets 2 criteria:

1. timeslot that I set (ie 5:30 - 6:30 pm)
2. can filter based on value Co-Ed or Women's Only

[image: book appt]

Unsure of how to filter these values. I though maybe searching the values of the row list

```
    timeslot = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("row.c-schedule-calendar__class-schedule-listitem-wrapper.c-schedule-calendar__workout-schedule-list-item")
```

Below is the html code

```
<li tabindex="0" class="row c-schedule-calendar__class-schedule-listitem-wrapper c-schedule-calendar__workout-schedule-list-item" data-index="22" data-workout-id="156986" data-club-id="204">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-2 time-duration clickable js-single-class-list-item">
                    <span class="js-class-time">7:45 pm</span> <span class="dot-separator">-</span> <span class="js-class-duration">8:45 pm</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-10">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-8 clickable js-single-class-list-item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="class-name"><span class="js-class-name">General Workout Area</span></div>
                                    <div class="class-short-info">
                                        <span class="js-class-type">Co-ed</span>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="class-address-wrapper">
                                        <span class="class-address">
                                            <svg viewBox="0 0 48 48" class="c-search-class-filter--location__pin-icon">
                                            <use xlink:href="/etc.clientlibs/goodlife/clientlibs/clientlib-site/resources/images/icons.svg#ic_pin_default"></use>
                                            </svg> Cambridge Hespeler And Eagle
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="col-4 c-schedule-calendar__cta-container">
                                <div class="js-class-action-container">
                                            <button class="c-btn-outlined class-action" data-class-action="book-class" data-class-action-step="class-action-confirmation" data-workout-id="156986" data-club-id="204" data-waitlistable="false"><span class="c-btn__label">Book</span></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="available-spots">
                                            <div class="js-available-spots-container">
                                                2 spots left
                                            </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
time_range = "5:30 pm - 6:30 pm"
category = "Co-Ed"
"//li[descendant::text()='{}' and descendant::span[text()='{}'] and descendant::span[text()='{}']]".format(time_range.split(' - ')[0],time_range.split(' - ')[1], category)
```

This xpath should work, so instead of searching by class element use

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[descendant::text()='{}' and descendant::span[text()='{}'] and descendant::span[text()='{}']]".format(time_range.split(' - ')[0],time_range.split(' - ')[1], category)).click()
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: can you give me url to page? 

maybe this can help
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-resolve-the-ElementNotInteractableException-in-Selenium-WebDriver

Comment: https://www.goodlifefitness.com/content/goodlife/en/book-workout.html#no-redirect
I tried with a time.sleep(5) before, and also tried using a timeslot that showed up at the top of the list (6 am - 7 am)

Comment: I noticed typo in my answer `span[text()='8:45 pm']` should be `span[text()='{}']`
Also add this div (with id 1 if you are on first day etc.) because there could be the same element on another day (filter on top)
`//div[@id='day-number-1']/li[descendant::text()='{}' and descendant::span[text()='{}'] and descendant::span[text()='{}']]`

Comment: Maybe you are not waiting enough, I think the best approach is to wait for that loader to dissaper with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082862/how-to-wait-until-an-element-no-longer-exists-in-selenium)
xpath for that is `//div[@class='c-schedule-calendar']//div[@class='c-accent-loader']`

Comment: the issue was with '@id='day-number-x'. thanks for the help!